# Similar UICollectionViewDataSource method for using it in Android?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to convert an iOS Xamarin app to Android Xamarin.I am facing a problem in finding appropriate similar methods in Android

Here is my iOS Xamarin code that I need to convert to Android Xamarin

```
public class HomeViewDS : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    public HomeViewDS ()
    {
    }

    public List<DBPlaylist> MyPlaylists{ get; set; }
    public List<TweakSet> MyDiscoveries{ get; set; }
    public event EventHandler ItemSelectedForPlaying;

    public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        if (MyPlaylists != null) {
            return MyPlaylists.Count;
        }
        if (MyDiscoveries != null) {
            return MyDiscoveries.Count;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CLLHomeItem v = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (CLLHomeItem.Key, indexPath) as CLLHomeItem;
        if (v == null)
            v = CLLHomeItem.Create ();
        if (MyPlaylists != null) {
            v.MyItem = MyPlaylists [indexPath.Row];
        }
        if (MyDiscoveries != null) {
            v.MyItem = MyDiscoveries [indexPath.Row];
        }            
        v.ItemSelectedForPlaying -= V_ItemSelectedForPlaying;
        v.ItemSelectedForPlaying += V_ItemSelectedForPlaying;
        return v;
    }

    void V_ItemSelectedForPlaying (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemSelectedForPlaying != null) {
            ItemSelectedForPlaying (sender, null);
        }
    }
}
```

So can any one give me an idea to convert this code to Android.If anyone can convert this I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Android uses a similar concept called an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). Similarly to a DataSource on iOS, it also implements ways to recycle items.

So it roughly translates into:

```
public class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    public List<DBPlaylist> MyPlaylists { get; set; }
    public List<TweakSet> MyDiscoveries { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler ItemSelectedForPlaying;

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view == convertView ?? CLLHomeItem.Create();
        if (MyPlaylists != null)
        {
            view.MyItem = MyPlaylists[position];
        }
        if (MyDiscoveries != null)
        {
            view.MyItem = MyDiscoveries[position];
        }
        view.ItemSelectedForPlaying -= V_ItemSelectedForPlaying;
        view.ItemSelectedForPlaying += V_ItemSelectedForPlaying;
        return v;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyPlaylists != null)
            {
                return MyPlaylists.Count;
            }
            if (MyDiscoveries != null)
            {
                return MyDiscoveries.Count;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void V_ItemSelectedForPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemSelectedForPlaying?.Invoke(sender, null);
    }
}
```

Then you can just assign it to your `ListView` `Adapter` property.

Comment: Thank You so much for the solution I am now going to implement it in my project.If I face any issue can I ask you ??